Connection between Lebesgue Measurability in different dimensions
If a subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is Lebesgue measurable, with non-zero measure, then for any $a>0$, does there always exists a unit speed piecewise smooth injective parametrization of a curve $\gamma: [0,a] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ is measurable, and has measure arbitrarily close to $a$?
Or, a weaker statement: does there exists a unit speed piecewise smooth injective parametrization of a curve $\gamma: [0,a] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma^{-1}(S)$ has outer measure arbitrarily close to $a$?
Intuition tells me that this statement should be true, and this problem can be reduced to looking at subset $S$ of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with measure close to $1$. If I look at the horizontal lines in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ my suspicion is
that there bound to be a line with outer measure greater than the measure of $S$. But I don't know where to go from here, nor do I know whether the statement is true or not.
